# Finding command line used when starting service with systemctl

Tags: systemd

I've just upgraded a system from 14.04 to 16.04 and among other issues, opendkim no longer starts correctly.  I have the following in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Sep 19 18:27:58 aurora systemd[1]: Starting DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter...
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: opendkim: usage: opendkim -p socketfile [options]
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-A          #011auto-restart
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-b modes    #011select operating modes
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-c canon    #011canonicalization to use when signing
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-d domlist  #011domains to sign
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-D          #011also sign subdomains
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-e name     #011extract configuration value and exit
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-f          #011don't fork-and-exit
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-F time     #011fixed timestamp to use when signing (test mode only)
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-k keyfile  #011location of secret key file
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-l          #011log activity to system log
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-L limit    #011signature limit requirements
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-n          #011check configuration and exit
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-o hdrlist  #011list of headers to omit from signing
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-P pidfile  #011file into which to write process ID
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-q          #011quarantine messages that fail to verify
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-Q          #011query test mode
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-r          #011require basic RFC5322 header compliance
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-s selector #011selector to use when signing
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-S signalg  #011signature algorithm to use when signing
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-t testfile #011evaluate RFC5322 message in "testfile"
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-T timeout  #011DNS timeout (seconds)
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-u userid   #011change to specified userid
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-v          #011increase verbosity during testing
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-V          #011print version number and terminate
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-W          #011"why?!" mode (log sign/verify decision logic)
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]: #011-x conffile #011read configuration from conffile
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=64
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora systemd[1]: Failed to start DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It appears that `opendkim` is getting invalid command line arguments.  How can I find out what command line is being used, and how it is constructed?

Tracing `/etc/init.d/opendkim start` does not help, since this just invokes  `/bin/systemctl --no-pager start opendkim.service`.  Looking around, I found `/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service` which contains the line

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p $SOCKET $DAEMON_OPTS
```

In `/etc/default/opendkim`, we have `SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost"` and `DAEMON_OPTS` left unset. However, if I manually run

```
/usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p inet:8891@localhost
```

it succeeds.  So apparently that is not the command line which is being used.

Following muru's comment, here is the output of `systemctl -l status opendkim.service`.

```
● opendkim.service - DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-09-19 18:27:59 UTC; 23min ago
     Docs: man:opendkim(8)
           man:opendkim.conf(5)
           man:opendkim-genkey(8)
           man:opendkim-genzone(8)
           man:opendkim-testadsp(8)
           man:opendkim-testkey
           http://www.opendkim.org/docs.html
  Process: 28496 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p $SOCKET $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=64)
  Process: 28488 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown opendkim.opendkim /var/run/opendkim (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28485 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/opendkim (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]:         -T timeout          DNS timeout (seconds)
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]:         -u userid           change to specified userid
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]:         -v                  increase verbosity during testing
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]:         -V                  print version number and terminate
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]:         -W                  "why?!" mode (log sign/verify decision logic)
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora opendkim[28496]:         -x conffile         read configuration from conffile
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=64
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora systemd[1]: Failed to start DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 19 18:27:59 aurora systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The `ExecStart` line is just as in the file.  Is it possible that it is literally passing the string `$SOCKET` rather than the contents of this variable?

Comment: Does `systemctl status opendkim.service` shed any light? IIRC it will list the command, but I don't have any system on hand to test.

Comment: @muru: Updated.

Comment: Does the service file say anything about the environment? Does it list `/etc/default/opendkim` as the `EnvironmentFile`?

Comment: @muru: Yes, `/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service` contains the line  `EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/opendkim`.  I assume the `-` is normal?

Comment: Yes, the `-` is normal, it indicates that a missing file is not a problem.

Comment: @muru: Resolved, see answer. :-)  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out.  I tried replacing `/usr/sbin/opendkim` with a script that logs its command line, and saw that it was getting

```
-x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p inet:8891@localhost# listen on loopback on port 12345
```

There was a comment at the end of the line in `/etc/default/opendkim` that evidently was not getting parsed correctly.

I moved that comment to its own line and now it works.

Comment: Ah, systemd EnvironmentFile files are not parsed exactly like shell scripts. It is parsed correctly - comment lines should *begin* with `#` or `;`

Comment: @muru: Yes, and I see now that the newly shipped version of /etc/default/opendkim conforms to that.  When I diffed it against my existing version (written for 14.04 with upstart, in which it actually is parsed by the shell AFAIK), I saw that I wanted to keep my setting of `SOCKET`, and all the other differences were apparently comments, so I just kept my version :-)

Comment: I wouldn't say that that correct way of parsing was *unlike* shell scripts.  *like* seems more apt.  In several shells, `#` only denotes a comment when it is at the start of a word.  The Korn shell, for one, is explicit about this in its manual.  The POSIX rules can certainly be read in this way, too.  In `inet:8891@localhost#` it isn't at the start of the word by a long chalk.

Comment: @JdeBP: There was a space before the `#` in the actual /etc/default/opendkim file.  The line was of the form `SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost" # comment`. I do not know why the space went away when it was passed to `opendkim`; that's part of the "incorrect parsing" I mentioned.  But the `#` was at the start of a word, though not at the start of the line.

Comment: I can't believe it. For me there were comments without space after # into the `/etc/opendkim` file 
Now it works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced "$SOCKET" with the actual socket value in the file `/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service` and got same problem working.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow had 2 `SOCKET`def on `/etc/default/opendkim`:

**This one:**

```
# default:
#SOCKET="local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock"
```

**And the newly added:**

```
# listen on loopback on port 8891
SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost"
```

This could be a very annoying issue to deal with so, here's my `/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service` file `ExecStart`

`ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p $SOCKET $DAEMON_OPTS`

And the same `ExecStart` on `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/opendkim.service`

And it worx fine.
Hope this helps someone.